# How can use CFFI to call an existing C function given the source code?

Tags: python, c, unit-testing, python-cffi

I have a C source/header file that are part of a bigger project. I would like to test this as a unit, independent of the real project. While it would be possible to do this in C by creating a new project with a different `main()`, I would like to see if I can use Python (3) and its frameworks (eg. nose) to accelerate the construction of tests, use existing reporting frameworks, etc.

I was under the impression that I could do this with CFFI. Here's a sample C file:

```
// magic.c
// Implementation of magic.
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a;
}
```

The header:

```
// magic.h
// Add two numbers (where a + b is not greater than INT_MAX).
int add(int a, int b);
```

Here's a script that just tries to compile it so I can call some functions:

```
# cffi_test.py
import cffi

INCLUDE_DIRS = ('.',)

SOURCES = ('magic.c',)

ffi = cffi.FFI()

ffi.set_source(
    '_magic_tests',
    '#include "magic.h"',
    include_dirs = INCLUDE_DIRS,
    sources = SOURCES,
    libraries = [],
    )

ffi.compile()
```

Ultimately I plan to have this be part of the setup before a set of unit tests eg. a pure Python function `test_add()` will call and check the result of the C function `add()` via the `ffi` object, which is constructed in the test setup.

The above script seems to work; it runs without error, it creates a `_magic_tests.c` file, a `_magic_tests.cp35-win32.pyd` file, and a `Release` directory. I can also `import _magic_tests` without an error.

But I can't figure out how to actually call a C function via CFFI. I can't find any documentation for the `set_source()` function, and it seems pretty integral to the whole process. The [overview](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.6/overview.html) mentions it a lot, but the [reference](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.6/ref.html) contains zero occurrences of it. The docs **do** have a section on [calling functions](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.6/using.html#function-calls), but it refers to some `lib` object without showing how it's created. If I look at the previous example there's a `lib` object created from `ffi.dlopen()`, but I don't see how to apply that to something that CFFI itself is producing.

My big question (ie. my [X problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/147348)) is:

- Is CFFI a reasonable tool to use for calling and testing C functions in a cross platform (Windows 7-10, Linux, OS X) way, and if it is, how?

The questions arising from my current approach (ie. my [Y problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/147348)) are:

- Where is the documentation for `set_source()`? How can I find out what arguments it takes?
- How do I produce `lib` objects that contain the functions I want to call?
- Is this the easiest way to use CFFI to call a C function? I do not particularly need or want a shared library or redistributable package to be produced; if it has to happen, that's fine, but it's not necessary. What other approaches could I try?

My current setup is:

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: [CPython 3.5.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/) 32 bit
- Pip: 8.1.2
- CFFI: 1.6.0
- C compiler: whatever comes with Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, linked from [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/)

I am using CFFI and pycparser from [Christoph Gohlke's repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycparser).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a project of mine, I use `cffi` to test my C code. IMHO `cffi` is a great tool to generate python bindings for C code and therefore think that it is a reasonable tool to use for calling and testing C functions from python. However, your code will only be as cross platform as the C code is, since you have to compile the binding for every platform.

Below you can find a few references to the documentation that should answer your questions. Additionally I wrote some example code to illustrate how you would use `cffi`. For a larger example, you can find my project at https://github.com/ntruessel/qcgc/tree/master/test.

- The documentation for `set_source()` can be found here https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html
- https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html explains how you can use CFFI, I recommend API, out-of-line.

Four your example, `build_magic_tests.py` would look something like this:

```
from cffi import FFI

ffibuilder = FFI()

# For every function that you want to have a python binding,
# specify its declaration here
ffibuilder.cdef("""
    int add(int a, int b);
                """)

# Here go the sources, most likely only includes and additional functions if necessary
ffibuilder.set_source("magic_tests",
    """
    #include "magic.h"
    """, sources=["magic.c"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile()
```

To generate the magic_tests module, you have to run `python build_magic_tests.py`. The generated module can be imported and used like this:

```
from magic_tests import ffi, lib

def run_add():
    assert 4 == lib.add(4, 5)
```

Comment: Great answer! My only further question is: it seems like there's some duplication between what's in the header file and what's in the `ffibuilder.cdef()` call; that is, I'd be declaring the function twice, and there's a risk it could get out of sync or introduce an error. Do you think there's a way to reduce that duplication?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is currently impossible, at least I did not find a way to do this. IMHO this is one of the major disadvantages of `cffi`. One could try to auto-generate the whole `build_magic_tests.py` using yet another script. However, this script has to work around the limitations of the `ffibuilder.cdef()` method.

Comment: Well, that's annoying but not a deal-breaker. It's still worth it to have access to Python's unit testing ecosystem. (And it's still less boilerplate than any C unit testing framework.)

Comment: I thought of one more question: how might you do cleanup? At the moment you import the module after compiling it, and you'd have to unimport it if you wanted to ensure a clean slate for every test. `ffi.compile()` returns the name of the `.pyd` file, which could be deleted, but there's a whole bunch of other stuff it generates for compilation which is compiler dependent. Do you know if there's a way to get at the `magic_tests.lib` object directly from CFFI calls?

Comment: Ah, it looks like I'm talking about what CFFI calls "API, in-line" ie. the `verify()` function. It's deprecated, so I'll just have to hack around it.

Comment: I felt like the quality of this answer deserved a little more rep than what you'll get for such a niche issue, and it really helped me out, so I added a bounty.